# Python 3: Find an element in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

```
houses={'apartment':15, 'penthouse':35, 'others':[20,5,70]}
```

what I need is to check and then find 20 for example.

been trying for hours.
would be great if you could provide and explanation and multiple solutions.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `print(20 in houses['others'])` ?

Comment: You could use `any`: `any(20 in v for k, v in houses.items()`

Comment: I missed a close bracket in my last comment, it should be: `any(20 in v for k, v in houses.items())`

Comment: thank you alfasin. it works. but can I not find what I want in general?. what if I don`t know that 20 is in another list in the dictionary?.

Comment: @ArthurTacca it does't work consistently. once I get a True and the next I get `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`.

Comment: @nightroad I didn't notice that some of the values are just lone values. I've posted an answer that takes it into account. But if you control the code that builds `houses` in the first place, I suggest you make all the values lists, even if they only have one item in them, and use the code in my earlier comment; that would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `houses` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). It is missing a `}` though.  Its `others` key is a [list](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex34.html), so you can access its first item like so: print (houses['others'][0]). If you need to iterate over the keys and values, there are several ways as demonstrated in this link:[Iterating over dict values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733685/iterating-over-dict-values)
. A basic version  is like this:

```
houses={'apartment':15, 'penthouse':35, 'others':[20,5,70]}
bool = False
for (k,v) in houses.items():
    if type(v)==list:
        if 20 in v:
            bool = True
            print(k,v)
    if v == 20:
        bool = true
        print(k,v)
print(bool)
```

Comment: the braces is already in my code. just missed it here. but thank you.  adding [0] is't helpful tho, because I need to find the data before I know where is its location.

Comment: Dictionary keys and values can be accessed like in this link: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/50721fce7c7091000201e56a    where the author 'flatten a list using a listcomp with two 'for'' : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

This will look over all the entries in `houses`, and look for `search` in the values. For each value, if it's not a collection, it will compare directly.

```
def is_in_house(search, house):
    for v in houses.values():
        try:
            if search in v:
                return True
        except TypeError:
            if v == search:
                return True
    return False
```